# What is the definition of integrable tensor?

Tags: tensors

I just googled 'integrable tensor' but I haven't found any stuff about it. I know this question is silly but the rigid definition is also important. Thanks in advance.

I saw this word here :

**Definition** Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. A divergence-free positive symmetric tensor is a locally integrable tensor $x \mapsto A(x)$ over $\Omega$ with the properties that $A(x)\in \text{Sym}_d^{+}$ almost everywhere, and $\text{Div}A=0$.

My guess : Each entries of the tensor is integrable.

Comment: Context helps, where did you see this expression ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Thanks for comment I put it in my question.

Comment: I should think the definition pastes over from a locally integrable function,whereby a function is called locally integrable if, around every point in the domain, there is a neighborhood on which the function is integrable. I assume locally integrable tensors are broadly equivalent.

Comment: @Kevin Oh I thought so too. Could you write it down specifically? Then we all can see if we are thinking samely.